# Angular full calendar ver 5- hide past dates or disable click on past dates

Tags: javascript, angular, fullcalendar, hide, fullcalendar-5

I am developing a meal planner that allows users to choose the plan date.
I do not need to schedule events, I just need the date clicked (I need only dayClick).

Version:

> ```
> "@fullcalendar/angular": "^5.5.0",>     
> "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "^5.5.0",>     
> "@fullcalendar/interaction": "^5.5.0",
> ```

The code:

```
export class DateSelector {

    currentDate : Date = new Date();
    
    calendarOptions: CalendarOptions = {
      initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
      dateClick: this.handleDateClick.bind(this),
      validRange : {
        start : this.currentDate, //start is today
        end : getEndDate() //end is 6 months from today
      }
    };
  
    handleDateClick(arg) {
      console.log('date click! ' + arg.date); //Logs date correctly
    }
    
    getEndDate() : Date {
        this.currentDate.setMonth(this.currentDate.getMonth() + 6);
        return this.currentDate;
    }
}

<div class="row text-center">
  <full-calendar
  [options]="calendarOptions"></full-calendar>
</div>
```

What I currently see:
The calendar correctly greys out/disables the past dates with no numbers displayed.
The trouble is if say start is the 24th, the calendar looks ugly.

I want a way where either
(1) The calendar starts today i.e. past days are hidden.
(2) The disabled past dates look better - the nos are displayed and greyed out, but they are not clickable.

Comment: try using selectAllow https://fullcalendar.io/docs/selectAllow

Comment: The validRange option might help you

Comment: HiADyson, I am using validRange and it does what I want. The trouble is it makes my calendar look ugly. Imagine today is Jan 31 and Jan 1-30 are greyed out - the ui will look pretty bad.

Comment: This is just what fullCalendar does. Not sure what you want us to do about it? You can try customising the CSS or something if you really want to change the appearance, I guess. Sorry to be negative but this just sounds like a moan than any kind of problem solving question. Have you attempted to do anything to alter it so far as per your preference?

Comment: Hi ADyson, Sorry I wasn't moaning. I tried selectAllow, I tried adding css classes and it did not change the appearance. I thought the calendar would have a setting to hide past dates. I guess I will have to switch to a different calendar now. Do you have any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I'm not certain I'll be of much help to the second half of your question regarding greying out past dates as a part of the same cycle, but I do have some code that works with the 'Locales.html' example to create a variable with today's date. It's also worth mentioning I'm not using the angular file set (I think I have the react files). You could effectively plug this in

```
var theDate = new Date();
var dd = String(theDate.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
var mm = String(theDate.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0'); //January is 0!
var yyyy = theDate.getFullYear();

theDate = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;
```

Just pass your variable name in this `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function()` as the `initialDate` parameter.

As far as greying out the numbers, you could use the date variable created above, `dd`, as a check within a for loop. Something like

```
function myFunction() {
for (i=0; i<dd; i++) {
document.getElementsByClassName("fc-daygrid-day-number").style.color = "#aaa"; }
}
```

I'm not very good with javascript yet, but that should, in theory, change the color of all dates of the month prior to today to grey. You'll likely have to look for some way to prevent from greying out these days for the following months, but I hope this is a starting point!

Answer (score -1):

you can add `firstDay:{getDay(new Date())}` it get the day number and start the calendar from that date